# moving jquery autocomplete code snippet to script.js file

Tags: php, javascript, autocomplete

I'm trying to keep true to the DRY principle by moving my jquery auto complete code to a scripts.js file but i'm having trouble getting the auto complete functionality to work when i move it.

Here's how its setup at the moment.

**add form**

```
    <head>
    <?php
     require_once ('includes/connect-db.php');
     require_once ('includes/functions.php');
    ?>
        <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


        $('document').ready(function() {
            $('#datepickerID').datepicker({
                changeYear:true,
                changeMonth:true,
                dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
            })

        <?php $productArray = autoComplete();?>

        $(function() {

                var js_products_array = <?php echo json_encode($productArray); ?>;

                $( "#autocompleteID" ).autocomplete({
                    source: js_products_array
                 });
            });

        });

        </script>
</head>
```

I'm uncertain as to how to get this to work between the addForm.php and scripts.js when there is embeded php code in the javascript, if that makes sense.

Comment: How is that related to MySQL at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to keep `js_products_array` outside of the `.js` file as it contains data from PHP scripts and initilize the `autocomplete()` on document ready.

so you can keep only

```
<?php $productArray = autoComplete();?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var js_products_array = <?php echo json_encode($productArray); ?>;
</script>
```

and in your `file.js` you can add

```
 $('document').ready(function() {
     $('#datepickerID').datepicker({
           changeYear:true,
           changeMonth:true,
           dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
     })

     $( "#autocompleteID" ).autocomplete({
           source: js_products_array
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. If its not possible, i'm left with adding it to each file editForm.php, searchForm.php etc. I think i maintain readability if i keep the code together but i'm interested to know if its best practice to split it up like the above? Thanks.

Comment: You can also make the javascript file actually an php file and print out only javascript data like `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.php"></script>`